# What does the /subscriber/.gitkeep directory or folder do for TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

In the settings we create this folder for some reason, I couldn't find any information on it. Why is it necessary?

```
subscribers: [ 'code/database/subscriber/**/*.js'],
subscribersDir: 'code/database/subscriber',
```

Comment: perhaps it's needed for this? https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/sample/sample5-subscribers/subscriber/EverythingSubscriber.ts

Comment: Yes that was my guess, but what does that actually need to do with an empty directory?

Comment: maybe some files are generated at runtime there? I think you should ask the owner directly, anyway. Or maybe we can bump him here in some way.

Comment: There are 91 watchers for the typeorm tag, I figured someone will know the answer. If not, I'll post the link here on github